# Is there a way to show simple graph visualisation in python without any import packages

Tags: python, graph

I have a dictionary which contains the parent and child tables as key:value pairs.I have to show the dependency of the tables in a simple visualisation (graph or tree)without any import packages

Comment: If you don't want to import anything you will have to write the visualization yourself.

Comment: Also, if you can mention whats the reason behind the "no imports" constraint, that will be a great add on for the question.

Comment: @KlausD.  Can you tell me any examples or references of how to do that?

Comment: @JimTodd i'm writing a function which is independent of any packages

Comment: We don't like to give external references and your question is far too broad to give an example.

Comment: Your question is too broad, mate. What kind of graph or tree? Terminal, web, scientific notebook? You can look at open source implementations of what you are looking for and basically redo it (which probably makes no sense). Even if you are going to be implementing your own independent implementation, you may end up having to rewrite so much code that it will make no practical sense at all.

Comment: Without seeing the data (or example data) and a mockup of the graph, we probably won't be able to help you much I think. Besides: think what doing this without import packages would entail: your output would have to be something like HTML, or a bitmap file, or ASCII art. You can't easily re-implement complicated image formats, and even the aforementioned output formats could be tough, and you can't display graphics on the screen without an import.